# PHP to MySQL and Google sheet?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, google-forms

A few months ago, my supervisor needed me to create a form to collect some data - at the time, the most sensible thing to do was just to whip together a Google Form, no problem.  Now it turns out that the data collection program needs to expand, and it makes more sense to direct the form to a MySQL database (using PHP) instead - again, no problem, already done.  However, for reasons I won't elaborate on here, my supervisor still wants that data to go to the original Google Sheet as well.

My question - is it possible to submit form data to two separate sheets when one is a MySQL table and the other is a Google Sheet?

Thanks!

Comment: it's just code, so... yes?

Comment: Never have used code to write to a Google Sheet, but maybe look into the Google Drive API. [Quick Google](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client)

Comment: PHPExcel Class would solve your problem, but with excel format.  Not sure if that would actually help or not.

Comment: PHP can make an HTTPS GET or POST request.  Apps Script can handle a HTTPS GET or POST request with `doGet()` or `doPost()`.  If it's a GET request, you need to use a search string in the URL.  With POST you don't need to construct a search string.  You can also use the Google sheets API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that feel bro ;)

There's some resources to handle boss requests:

1. [PHPExcel Class](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) is a library written in pure PHP and providing a set of classes that allow you to write to and read from different spreadsheet file formats, like Excel (BIFF) .xls, Excel 2007 (OfficeOpenXML) .xlsx, CSV, HTML...
2. You will need an script to process the outputs.
3. [Excel / CSV > MySQL](https://github.com/nickedes/Excel-to-MySQL)
4. [MySQL > Excel / CSV](https://github.com/linmic/mysql-to-excel/blob/master/main.php)

If you need directly to work with Google Docs, you will have to follow the previous steps and play with the following project:

[php-google-spreadsheet-client](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client) is a library that provides a simple interface to the Google Spreadsheet API.

You will need to store data in MySQL and pass it to Google.

Second idea:

If your boss neet it NOW, you can give a chance to [Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/google-docs/mysql/) and do it fast. If you don't need a very fast sync time, it can be a good free option.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks man - I ended up convincing my boss to get off of the Google sheet and just let me make her a separate table in MySQL.  She was a little intimidated about using MySQL, but I showed her what to do and it's all good.  Still, I will leave this question up here since you provided some helpful resources, and perhaps someone else will stumble into this problem one day.